# View Google App Engine Memory Usage by Instance

Tags: google-app-engine

I have an app running in Google App Engine which has multiple instances.

If I go to App Engine > Instances
Select the service and Chart "Memory Usage" I can see the memory usage across all instances.

How can I chart the memory usage for a single instance?

Answer (score 0):

You can view the memory usage for each instance by either going to [App Engine Dashboard](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine) or [App Engine Instances](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/instances). You can select the `service` and the `version(s)` for each service (if multiple versions are available for each service). Please check the screenshots below:

[image: 3]

[image: 4]

Let me know if you have questions or clarifications.